# Ошибка 500 при подключении к собственному сайту

Tags: python, flask

Изучаю создание веб-сайтов на Flask и столкнулась со следующей проблемой:
изначально проект создан на макбуке и залит на github, далее склонировала репо на ПК и при подключении к серверу высвечивается ошибка 500. При том на маке все также исправно работает, а вот на ПК никак не хочет запускаться. В чем может скрываться причина?

[image: вывод в консоли]

Comment: А сам сайт что-то пишет в логах? Если логирования нет - добавьте )  Как минимум Flask какую-то диагностику должен выводить

Comment: не знаю ничего о логах, но при ошибке пишет "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." То есть ошибка в приложении? Текст из консоли прикрепила к обсуждению.

Comment: Может быть, в пути к шаблону есть ошибки? Это две разные системы, у которых есть различия в работе с файловой системой.

Comment: Да, вон оно пишет, что шаблон index.html не может найти